# "EACCESS: permission denied" with Webpack run in a Docker container with a USER set in the dockerfile

Tags: docker, npm, webpack, docker-compose, file-permissions

I've been using docker containers for a couple years but I've just recently decided that I need to improve the security and user management of the container by declaring a USER within the Dockerfile.

My setup works on Windows 10, but I get a permission error on Mac.

By the way, I'm using docker-compose to build and run everything and I've installed Docker Toolbox.

So, this is what I've added to the docker file:

```
# add node user
RUN groupadd --system --gid 61000 buink-group
RUN useradd --no-log-init --system --uid 61000 --gid buink-group node-user
RUN chgrp --recursive buink-group /var/www/html
RUN chmod g+rwx /var/www/html

...

# set user as node-user
USER node-user
```

I use a file called start.sh as the entry point and within that file I run:

```
npm run watch-poll
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
node-container | 
 95% emittingError: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/html/public/js'
node-container | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
node-container | npm ERR! errno 1
node-container | npm ERR! @ watch: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=webpack.config.js "--watch-poll=200"`
node-container | npm ERR! Exit status 1
node-container | npm ERR! 
node-container | npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script.
node-container | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
node-container | 
node-container | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
node-container | npm ERR!     /home/node-user/.npm/_logs/2018-09-13T18_58_07_373Z-debug.log
node-container | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
node-container | npm ERR! errno 1
node-container | npm ERR! @ watch-poll: `npm run watch -- --watch-poll=200`
node-container | npm ERR! Exit status 1
node-container | npm ERR! 
node-container | npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch-poll script.
node-container | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
node-container | 
node-container | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
node-container | npm ERR!     /home/node-user/.npm/_logs/2018-09-13T18_58_07_395Z-debug.log
node-container exited with code 1
```

Here are the volumes in my docker-compose.yml file

```
volumes:
  - ./:/var/www/html
  - composer:/var/www/html/vendor
  - node_modules:/var/www/html/node_modules
```

Comment: Sharing the `docker-compose.yml` file would be helpful.  In particular, if you're using a volume to overwrite everything that's installed in the Dockerfile, there are further lurking permission issues.

Comment: I would delete `node_modules` and run the install again. Most of the time, it should fix the permission issues

Comment: @RuChernChong I do a docker-compose down -v every time which based on the volume should delete the volume.

Also, I do `npm cache clean --force` in the docker file.

Comment: @DavidMaze I added it above.